Delphi Template creating blanks around code
I have the following template code to wrap a int-variable in a string inside of parenthesis and plus-signs but i creates wild blanks all around. I have no idea why
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<codetemplate   xmlns="http://schemas.borland.com/Delphi/2005/codetemplates"
                version="1.0.0">
    <template name="StringInsertInt" invoke="manual">
        <description>
            Insert a text variable into a string
        </description>
        <author>

        </author>
        <code language="Delphi"  delimiter="|" ><![CDATA['+IntToStr(|selected|)+']]>
        </code>
    </template>
</codetemplate>

this is what happens:
  reply:='This is a demo for INTVAR.';
  reply:='This is a demo for                              '+IntToStr(  INTVAR)+'.';

Additionally I havent yet figured out how to make this template appear in the "surround" dialog. I have to manually select it from the templates window.

I cannot say why the blanks appear (looks like a bug), but to list the template in the surrounds you need to add the attribute surround="true" in the template node.
